# c++ reading from beginning of file to a specified byte

Tags: c++, seekg

Trying to write a file that reads from the first byte in a file to a byte specified by the user. I need help on the logic. If the file just has letters a through z and I just want to read and display the first 10, for example. here's a piece of what I wrote:

```
  char byte;
  inFile.seekg(0L,ios::beg);
  inFile.get(byte);
  cout << byte;

  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++);  //num is an int specified by the user.
  {
      inFile.seekg(1, ios::cur);
      inFile.get(byte);
      cout << byte;
  }
```

Comment: What's your question? Is the code working? If not, what's the problem?

Comment: Your problem is probably that you don't need to seek forward 1 byte after every read. The `get` call already does that. Your code is probably skipping every second byte. Also, you're reading one more byte than you need because your loop goes from 0 to num-1, in addition to the get before the loop.

Comment: `seek` is for when you don't want to read sequentially from the begining of the file.

Comment: BTW, you should also consider checking for the end of the file... You could read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/eof/

Comment: Do you want to skip a number of bytes or do you want to search for a byte value?

Comment: Are you searching in binary (no translations) or in text mode?

Answer (score 1):

First problem - the semi-colon on the end of the `for()` line:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++);
    {
        ...
    }
```

What the compiler sees is actually this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) { /* do nothing num times */ }

    {
        // code that will only run once
    }
```

So, remove the semi-colon.

Next, if you're just reading bytes in succession, there's no need to seek in between each one. Just calling `get()` will get the next byte in the sequence. So remove the `seekg()` calls.

Final problem - this function is actually calling `inFile.get()` a total of `num + 1` times. The first call is before the `for` loop. Then in the `for` loop, `get()` is called `num` times (ie. i = 0, 1, 2, 3 ... num-1). You can fix this either by changing the `for` loop counter to `(i = 1; i < num; i++)` or just removing the `get()` call before the `for` loop. In the code below I've chosen the second way:

```
void run(int num, istream &inFile)
{
    char byte;

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        inFile.get(byte);
        cout << byte;
    }
}
```